# Managing sequence of text and images

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

It is necessary for me to handle sequences of text and images in this way:

- Pictures internal notice: in case we find DESCRIPTION \ IMG, the
  value of the SRC is equal to the first ATTACHED_FILENAME.
- External Images notice: in this case there is no second DESCRIPTION /
  IMG and the the second ATTACHED_FILENAME is alone.

In practice I associate to each IMG the respective ATTACHED_FILENAME but if does not exist the respective IMG the ATTACHED_FILENAME in this case is an external image to the alert.

This is my XML:

```
 <NTC_SD_NOTICE>
<PUBLISH_NUMBER>2 caso</PUBLISH_NUMBER>
<PUBLICATION_REF>
  <PUBLICATION_SHORT_TITLE>Portolano P8</PUBLICATION_SHORT_TITLE>
  <PUBLICATION_EDITION_YEAR>2013</PUBLICATION_EDITION_YEAR>
  <PUBLICATION_PAGE>128</PUBLICATION_PAGE>
</PUBLICATION_REF>
<REGION>15-Mar Ligure - Francia (Corsica)</REGION>
<VICINITY>Appartamento tuo</VICINITY>
<SUBJECT>Fotografie</SUBJECT>
<AUTHORITY>Compamare Arzachena</AUTHORITY>
<PROJECT>230/8562</PROJECT>
<INSTRUCTION_LIST>
  <INSTRUCTION_LIST_ITEM>
    <NTC_SD_INSTRUCT>
      <ACTION>Inserire</ACTION>
      <PLACEMENT>dopo la riga 1:</PLACEMENT>
      <DESCRIPTION>
        <P>Dietro al monte si vede una meda cardinale sud.</P>
        <P>
          <IMG border="0" hspace="0" alt="" align="baseline" src="C:\Users\l_sturla\Desktop\meda.JPG"/>  <-- First image
        </P>
      </DESCRIPTION>
      <ATTACHMENT_LIST>
        <ATTACHMENT>
          <ATTACHED_FILENAME>meda.JPG</ATTACHED_FILENAME> <-- Attribute first image
        </ATTACHMENT>
        <ATTACHMENT>
          <ATTACHED_FILENAME>altro.JPG</ATTACHED_FILENAME> <-- In this case there are no second IMG, this is an external image.
        </ATTACHMENT>
      </ATTACHMENT_LIST>
    </NTC_SD_INSTRUCT>
  </INSTRUCTION_LIST_ITEM>
  <INSTRUCTION_LIST_ITEM>
      <NTC_SD_INSTRUCT>
        <ACTION>Sostituire</ACTION>
        <PLACEMENT>le righe 34 &#xF7; 50 con:</PLACEMENT>
        <DESCRIPTION>Proseguire per il centro del canale e prestare attenzione al relitto sulla dritta.</DESCRIPTION>
        <ATTACHMENT_LIST>
          <ATTACHMENT>
            <ATTACHED_FILENAME>relitto.JPG</ATTACHED_FILENAME>
          </ATTACHMENT>
        </ATTACHMENT_LIST>
      </NTC_SD_INSTRUCT>
    </INSTRUCTION_LIST_ITEM>
  </INSTRUCTION_LIST>
</NTC_SD_NOTICE>
```

This is my XSLT 1.0:

Template for internal image: (it run very well thank to Martin Honnen)

```
<!-- TEMPLATE PER LE IMMAGINI INTERNE ALL'AVVISO -->
<xsl:template match="//IMG">
    <span style="font-style:italic">
        <img src="{key('attachment-by-pos', concat(generate-id(ancestor::NTC_SD_INSTRUCT), '|', count(../preceding-sibling::*//IMG)))/ATTACHED_FILENAME}"/> 
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

Template for external image: (not work - all ATTACHED_FILENAME that are not associated to an IMG)

```
<xsl:template name="allegati">
    <center><xsl:text>Allegati:</xsl:text></center>
    <xsl:for-each select="INSTRUCTION_LIST/INSTRUCTION_LIST_ITEM/NTC_SD_INSTRUCT/ATTACHMENT_LIST/ATTACHMENT/ATTACHED_FILENAME">
            <center>
                <img src="{key('attachment-by-pos', concat(generate-id(ancestor::NTC_SD_INSTRUCT), '|', count(../preceding-sibling::*//IMG)))/ATTACHED_FILENAME}"/> 
            </center>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

In this case the output must be:

Inserire dopo la riga 1: Dietro al monte si vede una meda cardinale sud.
-IMMAGINE MEDA.jpg- 

Sostituire le righe 34 ÷ 50 con: Proseguire per il centro del canale e prestare attenzione al relitto sulla dritta.

**Allegati:

-IMMAGINE altro.jpg-


-IMMAGINE relitto.jpg -** 

This part highlighted with bold text don't run.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your previous question, the answer given by Martin Honnen defines the following key, to look up `ATTACHMENT` elements by their position within the `NTC_SD_INSTRUCT` element.

I think for your new requirement you are reversing the logic, so you could also define a key to look up `IMG` elements by their position

```
<xsl:key name="img-by-pos" match="NTC_SD_INSTRUCT/DESCRIPTION/P/IMG" use="concat(generate-id(ancestor::NTC_SD_INSTRUCT), '|', count(../preceding-sibling::*//IMG))"/>
```

Then, in the `xsl:for-each` in your `allegati` template, you would use this key to check if their is an associated `IMG`

Try this template instead

```
<xsl:template name="allegati">
    <center><xsl:text>Allegati:</xsl:text></center>
    <xsl:for-each select="INSTRUCTION_LIST/INSTRUCTION_LIST_ITEM/NTC_SD_INSTRUCT/ATTACHMENT_LIST/ATTACHMENT
                          [not(key('img-by-pos', concat(generate-id(ancestor::NTC_SD_INSTRUCT), '|', count(preceding-sibling::ATTACHMENT))))]">
            <center>
                <img src="{ATTACHED_FILENAME}"/> 
            </center>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for your precious collaboration.